# how to connect angularjs with sql adapter?

Tags: angularjs, ibm-mobilefirst, ionic-framework

How to connect Angular JS with SQL adapter?

login page to fetch data from database using AngularJS and SQL adapter?

please share if any sample code or any useful links.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: angularjs is client side framework .You have to either use asp.net or node.js or php to make the service for angular.

Comment: I'm trying with ionic and AngularJs to connect SQL adapter in worklight.

Answer (score 0):

Worklight Adapters are server-side entities that enable you to retrieve data from  various backend systems, such as a database. Therefore there is no direct relation between AngularJS and adapters.

As written in the comments, AngularJS is a client-side framework... one amongst many. And at the bottom line it's still simply JavaScript.

In your Worklight application logic, which is written in JavaScript, you call the adapter as you would always call it. If you don't know how to use adapters, go ahead and read about it:

- [Adapters Overview](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-0/server-side-development/adapter-framework-overview/)

You can then also review the following materials that talk about AngularJS and Worklight applications:

- [Using Angular JS and Ionic on IBM Worklight](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a89W_atlhjg)
- [Building Worklight Applications with AngularJS](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/building_worklight_applications_with_angularjs?lang=en)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to make changes in your SQL Adapter file where you need to mention your

`<url>database URL</url> 
<user> Username</user>
<password>Password</password>`

Before `</wl:adapter>` you need to declare your procedures 
`<procedure name = "name of the function from where you would be firing your query"/>`

Then in your Adapters .js file you would be writing you query and defining your function.

Comment: That one I have done already, SQL adapter is working fine. I want to do login page the username and password want to get it from database using Angular Js and SQL adapter.                                                                                                        SQL adapter want to call Angular Js(front end)